# how to store Arraylist of object to store and retrieve from SDCard

Tags: android

I have ArrayList of object like

```
ArrayList<DataCCHeading>CC1=new ArrayList<DataCCHeading>();
ArrayList<DataCCHeading>hd=new ArrayList<DataCCHeading>(result);

for (DataCCHeading dataCCHeading : hd)
{
    if(dataCCHeading.Ownername==TAG_CC1HeadingData)
    {
        CC1.add(dataCCHeading);
    }
}
```

What I want to do to store external storage SDCard  so that I can later get that data other wise I have to request it again from server. My question is how to store Arraylist of object to store and retrieve from SDCard?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
  //use getExternalStorageState to determine if there is an sd card
  if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
                    directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                            + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                    photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                            + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                    /*
                     * this checks to see if there are any previous test photo files
                     * if there are any photos, they are deleted for the sake of
                     * memory
                     */
                     //if the directory exists, delete files in directory
                    if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                        File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                        if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                            for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                                dirFiles[ii].delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if no directory exists, create new directory
                    if (!directory.exists()) {
                        directory.mkdir();
                    }

                    // if phone DOES have sd card
                } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
                    // search for directory on SD card
                    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                    photoDirectory = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                    if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                        File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                        if (dirFiles.length > 0) {
                            for (int ii = 0; ii < dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                                dirFiles[ii].delete();
                            }
                            dirFiles = null;
                        }
                    }
                    // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
                    // results
                    if (!directory.exists()) {
                        directory.mkdir();
                    }
                }
```

It is a pretty easy process. What I did here was check to see if there is an SD card, if there is, I search for a directory, if no directory, I create one. If there is a directory and it has content I erase it. You don't have to do all that. If you like, you can use the the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. This will get the SD card. From there you create a `bufferedWriter` and write. You also need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest. If you have any questions, let me know.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks to All guys who answers this question.i get data from server..using Aysnctask and store in Array list of object.i want to store this data in external storage ..not in sqllite...later i want to access.some one ..is telling Serialize object.can u please make the code.i am new in android

Comment: This is not that, what OP wants  " My question is how to store Arraylist of object to store and retrieve from SDCard?"

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

Java Serialization: Just make your class implements Serializable, and write the appropriate serialize and deserialize logic, and you can write them to a file and read it back. See this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

JSON serialization: Use a library list GSON, you can serialize your objects to a JSON array as a text file, save it to a file. Then read it back as a JSON string and use the GSON library again to convert it back to an arraylist of your object.

Use built-in SQLiteDatabase: Store your objects as rows of data in a sqlite database. Class members will be stored as columns in a table. To convert them back to an array, just retrieve all rows from the table, build the object one by one and add them to an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to serialise it into something first (e.g.: using JYaml).

Then you can easily de/serialise, and it's quite space efficient.

Comment: This is not right. You simply need to determine if there is and SD card, if there is, find the SD card, create a directory (if you like) then write the file. Serialize has nothing to do with it. -1.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP wants to know, how to store his arraylist to a file. You need some sort of serialization for this to work.

Comment: @BlaineOmega : **"Serialize has nothing to do with it."** - WRONG. Serialization is most definitely an option for what the OP is asking - did you actually read the question? The OP wants to save an `ArrayList` to a file. Your answer shows a whole bunch of irrelevant code which doesn't even include an `ArrayList` and has references to things like `photoDirectory` and `Robotium` (what relevance do they have?). I have no idea why the OP accepted your answer and if you look at their comment on it, he/she is now asking for code on how to serialize objects.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but it looks like you didn't even bother to read the code. If you did, you would realize that `photoDirectory` and `Robotium` were just the platform I used for the code. Nothing to do with this. And who knows, maybe the OP author didn't really know what they wanted. I don't know why they accepted, other than they did. Oh well. Have a nice day.